# Entity framework code first migration always tries to create new database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I do every step on that video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7SDd5JcjN4

1. PM> enable-migrations
2. Change my entity model (add some property)
3. PM> add-migration migrationName

And there VS generate code for creation database anew. But I need to add just 1 property.

If you need code:
1. Generated with migration:

```
public partial class alter2 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Articles",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Content = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Chapters", t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Chapters",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Title = c.String(),
                    CreationDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    Level = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Url = c.String(),
                    Intro = c.String(),
                    Outro = c.String(),
                    MyProperty = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Articles", "Id", "dbo.Chapters");
        DropIndex("dbo.Articles", new[] { "Id" });
        DropTable("dbo.Chapters");
        DropTable("dbo.Articles");
    }
}
```

My entities:

```
public class Article {

    public int Id {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Content {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Chapter Chapter {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

public class Chapter {

    [ForeignKey ("Article")]
    public int Id {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Title {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime CreationDate {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Level {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Url {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Article Article {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Intro {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Outro {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int MyProperty {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

EF Context:

```
public class EFContext : DbContext {

    public EFContext () : base ("name=EFContext") {}

    public virtual DbSet<Chapter> Chapters {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Article> Articles {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating (DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Article> ()
                    .HasRequired (a => a.Chapter).WithOptional (a => a.Article);

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you already have an existing database? Usually it queries the database and spits out the full Migration if the database doesn't exist or is missing the migration history. Once it is created, it usually only gives you the changes since the last migration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an initial baseline migration. EF will always compare new migration to prior, so if you have nothing prior it's going to add code to create objects you already have in the database. So, do this after enabling migrations, but before making your model changes:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges
Update-Database
```

Now your next migration(s) will be incremental.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx#option1